# What is the term for two or more sets of source code in development that make changes to the same module?

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, application-lifecycle, test-environments

I'm trying to brainstorm and research different strategies/policies for different features that touch the same piece of code when building into a testing environment. I'm sure there's a term out there but not quite sure what it is so that I can yield relevant Google results.

At any point in time, we can have a large amount of features in development and testing from different stakeholders going at different paces that will wind up in the same application. Some changes can touch the same source but be near harmless, such as adding a method to a class. Others can be major such as reworking the entire class from the ground up. Yet others can be medium in nature and simply modify a method to make it more efficient.

As an example, having different features touch the same code file can hinder deadlines because of the risk that they may affect each other directly or indirectly.

Comment: Merge Conflict?

Comment: I think you're describing "strong coupling"